# Dropping multiple file formats in Snowflake at once

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I need to drop multiple file formats (around 70) of a particular schema in Snowflake. I went through the documentation and also tried some work arounds but couldn't find any way to do it automatically.

Example:

```
schema - work

file formats - work_123, work_234, preview_567, preview_561, match_897, match_565
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be fully automated with Snowflake Scripting:

```
DECLARE 
    SCHEMA_NAME STRING := 'WORK';
    FORMAT_NAME_PATTERN STRING := '%';
    QUERY STRING;
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT('BEGIN', CHAR(10)
             ,LISTAGG(CONCAT('DROP FILE FORMAT IF EXISTS '
                     ,FILE_FORMAT_SCHEMA, '.', FILE_FORMAT_NAME, ';', CHAR(10)), '')
             ,'END')
    INTO :QUERY
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILE_FORMATS
    WHERE FILE_FORMAT_SCHEMA ILIKE :SCHEMA_NAME
      AND FILE_FORMAT_NAME ILIKE :FORMAT_NAME_PATTERN ESCAPE '!'
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(());

  QUERY := COALESCE(QUERY, 'SELECT ''No file format found''');

  -- Uncomment to run
  -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
  RETURN :QUERY;
END;
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE SCHEMA WORK;


CREATE FILE FORMAT work_123 TYPE=csv;
CREATE FILE FORMAT work_232 TYPE=csv;
CREATE FILE FORMAT preview_567 TYPE=JSON;
```

The query to be executed is:

```
BEGIN
DROP FILE FORMAT IF EXISTS WORK.PREVIEW_567;
DROP FILE FORMAT IF EXISTS WORK.WORK_123;
DROP FILE FORMAT IF EXISTS WORK.WORK_232;
END
```

First run:

[image]

Subsequent run:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not fully automated - but writing a stored proc to fully automate it is probably overkill if this is a one off task.

1. Run show file formats
2. Construct the drop statements from the results of the previous command:

   SELECT 'DROP FILE FORMAT '||"name"||';'
   from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
3. Copy the output from the previous step and run it in your UI